# Spring boot not using custom deserialization on response

Tags: java, spring, groovy, deserialization

I have a issue where spring boot doesn't use my custom deserializer and I have honestly no idea why, custom serialization works just fine.

About the application(s): there are two sides, a server and a client side app, the client side reads the x509certificates serializes them just fine and sends them to the server app but the server app fails to deserialize it with the error:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class java.security.cert.X509Certificate]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 208] (through reference chain: eu.outerheaven.certmanager.controller.entity.Keystore["certificates"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->eu.outerheaven.certmanager.controller.entity.Certificate["x509Certificate"])
```

Relevant code is as follows:
Serialization

```
Class X509CertificateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<X509Certificate> {

    @Override
    void serialize(X509Certificate value,
                   JsonGenerator generator,
                   SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            BytesSerializer.serializeBytes(value.getEncoded(), generator, MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS);
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException exception) {
            throw new JsonMappingException("Unable to serialize X509 certificate", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    Class<X509Certificate> handledType() {
        return X509Certificate.class;
    }

}
```

Deserialization:

```
class X509CertificateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<X509Certificate> {

    private static final CertificateFactory certificateFactory;

    static {
        try {
            certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        } catch (CertificateException exception) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to access X.509 certificate factory");
        }
    }

    @Override
    X509Certificate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final byte[] data = BytesDeserializer.deserializeBytes(parser, MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS);
        final ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        try {
            return (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(input);
        } catch (CertificateException exception) {
            throw new JsonMappingException("Unable to parse X509 certificate", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    Class<X509Certificate> handledType() {
        return X509Certificate.class;
    }

}
```

Custom jackson:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
class CustomJacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        return (jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) -> {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializerByType(X509Certificate.class, new X509CertificateSerializer())
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(X509Certificate.class, new X509CertificateDeserializer())
        }
    }
}
```

Cert class:

```
@Entity
class Certificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id

    private Long agent_id

    private String alias
    
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private X509Certificate x509Certificate

    private Boolean managed

    private Long keystoreId
    
     ....getters and setters

}
```

Keystore class:

```
@Entity
class Keystore {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id

    //ID of keystore on the agent side
    private Long agentId

    //ID of instance under which this keystore is
    private Long instanceId

    private String location

    private String description

    private String password

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "keystoreId")
    private List<Certificate> certificates

    ...getters and setters
}
```

And the call itself:

```
private Keystore addToInstance(KeystoreForm keystoreForm){
        Instance instance = instanceRepository.findById(keystoreForm.getInstanceId()).get()
        PreparedRequest preparedRequest = new PreparedRequest()
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<KeystoreForm> request = new HttpEntity<>(keystoreForm, preparedRequest.getHeader(instance))
        ResponseEntity<Keystore> response
        try{
            response = restTemplate.postForEntity(instance.getAccessUrl() + api_url + "/add", request, Keystore.class)
            Keystore updatedKeystore = new Keystore(
                    agentId: response.getBody().id,
                    instanceId: instance.id,
                    location: response.getBody().location,
                    description: response.getBody().description,
                    password: response.getBody().password,
                    certificates: response.getBody().certificates
            )
            LOG.info("Agent with ip {}, hostname {} and port {} has added a new keystore under the path {}!",instance.getIp(),instance.getHostname(),instance.getPort(), updatedKeystore.getLocation())
            return updatedKeystore
        } catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error("Adding keystore to agent failed with error " + e )
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I mean I could but wouldn't that just be a slightly different implementation of what I am doing now?
Example, when I call a get request for a keystore on my client app in postman it returns a list of serialized certs like it should: https://pastebin.com/HjaLkNNL
I only now need to deserialize it on my end right? (do note, thats what I think , I am a sys engineer, this is by far the most complex project I have ever done)

Comment: Not the Java man, just sharing my 2 pence before someone gives an answer - your pastebin link is broken BTW

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I know I know, still thanks.
Pardon for that, pastebin admins removed the paste instantly for some reason, imgur link: https://i.imgur.com/MN6oBNR.png

Comment: Deserialise the certificate into a string instead of using a Jackson config and then do all of the string to certificate logic - `... certificateFactory.generateCertificate(input); ...` - after the JSON has been deserialised - that should 99% work

Comment: There's better ways definitely to do this in Java (which I'm not aware of) but that should fix your error for the time being at the very least

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it has been a while, nobody has been able to solve this issue so I gave in and did as you suggested, took a bit but works now flawlessly.

Comment: Wahey! If you tagged me again I’d have got something up in Java but I’m sure you would’ve gotten it sorted :) Add your own answer! I’m super glad buddy